# Implementation of a hash table in SWI-Prolog

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog, abstract-data-type

So I have to implement an ADT, in this case a hash table in SWI-Prolog.
I need help, because I'm new in this programming language, and don know how to start.

This started as an implementation in python(3) where I defined a class and added functions to work with (add, is_empty?, delete, rehash, hash, etc).
But now, I need to do something similar in prolog.

I have visited some other stackoverflow questions similar to mine, but I'm still helpless.

I expect to define a basic hash table and be able to add key+value data and some other basic functions. I'm not very sure if this is already implemented somewhere else.
Pls help.

Comment: Perhaps [library(pairs): Operations on key-value lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs)

Comment: @GuyCoder This sounds like a very bad idea. It is the opposite of a hash table.

Comment: In languages that lack destructive assignment and direct memory operations, one usually uses balanced trees to implement key-value maps instead of hash tables. Operations like `setarg/3` in such languages are usually dangerous or at least nonstandard. Balanced trees have different time and space complexity than hash tables but real hash tables usually subvert the persistence property of single-assignment variables anyway, and if they don't, you're often not getting the performance properties you think you're getting.

Comment: @DanielLyons You can do it, of course. See my answer. It will have the properties you expect of a hash map. `setarg/3` is backtrackable, so it isn't as bad as you make it sound. Definitely better than assert and retract, even if that will give you a real hash table. It is easy to come up with specific use cases for a hash-map data structure in Prolog. The real problem here is that we don't have a use case yet, so it is impossible to discuss benefits and drawbacks of any approach in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Several Prolog systems provide a term hash built-in or library predicate. For example, SWI-Prolog provides `term_hash/2` and `term_hash/4` built-in predicates. These predicates are often combined with first-argument indexing. A simple example:

```
% dynamic predicate to hold hash table entries
% with the term hash used as first argument to
% take advantage of first-argument indexing
%
% hash_table(Hash, Term).
:- dynamic(hash_table/2).

add_hash_table_entry(Term) :-
    nonvar(Term),
    term_hash(Term, Hash),      % or term_hash/4
    assertz(hash_table(Hash, Term)).

del_hash_table_entry(Term) :-
    nonvar(Term),
    term_hash(Term, Hash),  % or term_hash/4
    retractall(hash_table(Hash, _)).

hash_table_entry(Term) :-
    (   var(Term) ->
        hash_table(_, Term) 
    ;   term_hash(Term, Hash),  % or term_hash/4
        hash_table(Hash, Term)
    ).
```

Comment: But do you really have to do all this? What if you just assert, won't that give you a hash table with the first argument as a key? The hashed value itself won't be accessible but will that matter?

Comment: @User9213 It depends if the first argument of the compound term you are asserting is indexable or indexable in a useful way for common access patterns. It also depends if you will be accessing the terms by first argument, some other argument, or a some variable combination of arguments. A hash table may provide performance guarantees that you may not have with indexing. But only experimenting and measuring in a concrete case will tell you if a hash table is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a misguided idea. How is this "hash table" going to be used? What algorithmic complexity do you expect the different operations to have? Why do you want to *implement* a hash table in a language that doesn't need hash tables implemented by users?

The only half-decent way to do it will be to use a flat term for the table, one argument per bucket. If you have *k* buckets, then you use a term with that arity k, so for 256 buckets you get `hash_table/256`.

```
empty_hash_table(T) :-
    length(Buckets, 256),
    maplist(=(nil), Buckets),
    T =.. [hash_table|Buckets].
```

You can now use `arg/3` to get a bucket in constant time. You can use `setarg/3` to change them.

But this all is starting to sound very fishy. You need to explain your reasons better. Why do you want to implement a hash table in Prolog? How is it going to be used?